# Netlify: One Domain - Multiple Next.js Apps

Tags: next.js, netlify

Recently started my nextjs journey, so please have some patience ;)

I got two separate apps:

- Shop
- Blog

Currently I am hosting **shop** on the root of my netlify domain through github. I would like to host **blog** on this same domain. **Shop** should preferably be a sub-directory */shop* and the **blog** should be placed as the domain root.

Is there a way to «pack» my github project differently to include both apps in the desired structure?

Answer (score 0):

Subdirectories would interfere with NextJs's routing, so you would have to package the two apps together for that to work.

The usual solution to this is to use subdomains, ie `shop.companyname.com`, which can be set up to point to a different App in the Netlify Custom Domains settings.

Comment: Will using subdomains have any negative impact on SEO over the use of subdirectories?

Comment: @Fjott You don't necessarily have to use a single app, nor use subdomains. The shop app could be served from `/shop` with a [`basePath`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath) setup, while the blog app would be served from the root. They wouldn't interfere with each other.